# Calling Webservice with parameter value equal 1

Tags: c#, web-services, webmethod

I have a strange problem with webservices.
There is a `WebMethod` as below:

```
public string GenerateUrl(string webserviceId,string webmethodId, string versionId)
{
    return @"C:\" + webserviceId + @"\" + webmethodId + @"\Versions\V" + versionId + ".txt";
}
```

if I call it with the following parameters:

```
GenerateUrl("ws","wm","1");
```

it returns C:\\Versions\V1.txt

but if i pass `versionId` any other value than `"1"` like

```
GenerateUrl("ws","wm","2");
```

it works properly and returns C:\ws\wm\Versions\V2.txt!

Comment: and what is youre question?

Comment: What does it mean 'works properly'?

Comment: From what you've written it seems to work like it should. What ist your problem?

Comment: if versionId=1 regardless the values of the other parameters it works as the other parameters are empty string

Comment: What do you expect as retun values on different situations?

Comment: Okay I edited the question with the expected result. Sorry for being ambiguous.

Comment: Just tested it. `GenerateUrl("ws", "wm", "1")` returned `C:\ws\wm\Versions\V1.txt`. I can't find a problem.

Comment: Could you please include the code for your test cases, the ones that worked and the one that didn't please?

Comment: so it returns \\ instead of \   . This is the problem for you?

Comment: @Zefnus kindly recheck the question

Comment: @lordkain nope, if versionid=1 the other two parameters are received by the webmethod as empty string

Comment: doest solve problem but use String.Format like :         String.Format(@"C:\{0}\{1}\Versions\V{2}.txt", webserviceId, webmethodId, versionId);

Comment: functions works fine, i can only think that there is something different with passing first two parameters

Comment: @lordkain It works properly when I test it locally, but when I call the online service this issue occurs

Answer (score 0):

Just to test the case i have tried the following using a *Console Application* as a test project:

```
public static string GenerateUrl(string webserviceId, string webmethodId, string versionId)
{
    return @"C:\" + webserviceId + @"\" + webmethodId + @"\Versions\V" + versionId + ".txt";
}
```

And called it a couple times as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine(GenerateUrl("ws", "wm", "1"));            
Console.WriteLine(GenerateUrl("ws", "wm", "2"));            
Console.WriteLine(GenerateUrl("ws", "wm", "3"));
```

As expected the results (copied from console output) are:

> C:\ws\wm\Versions\V1.txt
>
> C:\ws\wm\Versions\V2.txt
>
> C:\ws\wm\Versions\V3.txt

In this case my final thought is the method `GenerateUrl()` works fine, there must be a problem the way it is being called. To see that i suggest you place a breakpoint and check for the arguments (watch) `webserviceId` and `webmethodId` each time method is called. You will probably see the values as `string.Empty` or `""`. Before executing `return` statement you can *manipulate* the value for `versionId` argument, set it to `1` and see if it's going to break

Comment: It works properly when I test it locally, but when I call the online service this issue occurs

Comment: @HebaEl-Fadly How and where do you call the `WebMethod` ? sharing more code would help finding what's going wrong

Comment: In another webservice by adding a Web Reference and make an object of it.